# How to create a gray background?

Tags: equations, mdframed

I am trying to make a gray background for equations like in the pic below using mdframe package but I could not download it properly , so is there another idea or how to download this package successfully?

Thanks in advance.

[image: this]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a lot of explanation, but I put only two more simple:

1. `mdframed` have a low power instead of `tcolorbox`, but in some circumstances it is easier to use;
2. I have simulated with the packages `newtxtext` and `newtxmath` the original font. I remember that the math fonts are of `mtpro2` where you can find the version lite on CTAN;
3. You can change the color in `backgroundcolor=gray!20` (I have used `xcolor` package).

---

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\mdfsetup{%
linecolor=white,
backgroundcolor=gray!20,
}
\begin{document}
\section{Two Little Tricky Classical \ldots}
\vspace{.7cm}
\begin{mdframed}
Prove that
\begin{equation}
   \mathrm{i}) \int_0^1\frac{\log^2(1+x)}{x}\,\mathrm{d}x=\frac14 \zeta(3); 
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
   \mathrm{ii}) \int_0^1\frac{\log(1-x)\log(1+x)}{x}\,\mathrm{d}x=-\frac58 \zeta(3), 
\end{equation}
where $\zeta$ denotes the Riemann zeta function.
\end{mdframed}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you but it didnt work for me. By the way, how to have a \vspace{.7cm} in each page of the book? it looks nicer.

Comment: Just a simple comment. I not know if you the TeX distribuition is outdated and what is your distribuition. For `\vspace{.7cm}` I have increase the distance between the section and the gray box. You can insert the additional vertical spacing manually. I didn't know you had to create a book. I also use additional spacing when I write something.

Comment: Thank you for the nice solition though.. much appreciated +1